# unexpected close/bounty interaction

Tags: feature-request

Turns out that a question with an open bounty cannot be migrated to another stack.

[This](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/18806/draytek-vigor-2925-outgoing-connection) question is off-topic. But, it does have an up-voted answer, so that would lead me to migrate it to Super User, rather than just closing it.

But, open bounty, so I cannot migrate . . .

**update**

I struck my, "(despite the community ignoring it and not close-voting)." commentary because, as Ryan points out, the community cannot close vote.

So this is definitely a bug. It means anyone with enough points to put a 50 point bounty on a Q, can nail it open if we don't on-hold/close it fast enough. (If I recall, there's a required stand-off before a new Q can have a bounty put on it.)

Comment: Turns out it can't be voted to close now, either.

Comment: FYI, the question is tagged bug, but I  don't think the behavior above is a bug

Comment: Wasn't obvious to me that I could refund/reject the bounty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Moderators have the option to remove/refund a bounty. In this case the bounty is refunded and then the question can be migrated.

In the future, if there is a bounty and the community feels it should be closed for various reasons, this is a time they should flag it for moderator attention.